# How to show tooltip for checkbox in react final-form?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, tooltip, react-bootstrap, react-final-form

I am using react final-form in my web application. Currently checkbox is required so that I am getting default tooltip : Please check this checkbox if you want to proceed

I want to change this tooltip text. is it possible to pass any FieldProp?

```
<Form.Check
    name={name}
    checked={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    onClick={onClick}
    onBlur={(e) => onBlur(e)}
    required={required}
    disabled={disabled}
    type="checkbox"
    label={inputLabel}
    className={inputClassName || ''}
  />
```

Comment: did you try using the `title` attribute like this `title="Your custom text` ?

Comment: yes I tried but not working like this @OlivierBoissé